# Does using 'dotted' namespaces have any significance in how Datomic indexes or other performance issues?

Tags: datomic

The Datomic docs (http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) state:

> Namespaces can be hierarchical, with segments separated by "." ...

Does using specifically 'dotted' notation (eg. "my.dotted.name/space") have any impact on the performance of the indexing etc in Datomic?

Put another way, could I use 'dashed' notation instead (eg. "my-dashed-name/space").

Would there be any impact on performance or other good reason to prefer dotted notation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason to use the `:ns.nestednamespace/attrname` convention is that it's the convention specified by the docs and that most databases conform to. The guidelines in the [schema docs](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) at present don't have a technical enforcement component (this is also true for the use of the `:db/` or `:db.` prefixed namespace), but they are quite clear about the expectations.

While there's little to no impact on indexing performance, etc., I would follow the convention unless you have a good reason not to.